# pandas to_csv will lose information between NaN and None

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I want to do turn a pandas dataframe into CSV. If I just use `to_csv`, I get:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"a": [1,2,3], 2: [2,3,float("NaN")], 3: ["a", None, "b"]})
>>> df
   a    2     3
0  1  2.0     a
1  2  3.0  None
2  3  NaN     b
>>> df.to_csv(index=False)
'a,2,3\n1,2.0,a\n2,3.0,\n3,,b\n'
```

I need the CSV to have `NaN`'s so I originally did the following:

```
>>> df.to_csv(index=False, na_rep="NaN")
'a,2,3\n1,2.0,a\n2,3.0,NaN\n3,NaN,b\n'
```

But then I realized that also maps `None`'s to `NaN`'s in the resulting CSV. I want to treat NaN's and Nones differently, but it seems like `na_rep` loses information between these two types.

This context isn't really needed, but I'll give it anyways: I'm trying to do a batch insert of the dataframe into postgres using `COPY FROM` which requires CSV. Postgres complains that a missing field in the CSV is not a valid numeric type, which means I need to map NaN's properly.

```
psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for type double precision: """"
```

Comment: `I want to treat NaN's and Nones differently` - what it means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If need convert `None` to empty strings is possible this trick - convert values to strings and compare by `None`s:

```
df = df.mask(df.astype(str).eq('None') & df.isna(), '')
print (df.to_csv(index=False, na_rep="NaN"))
a,2,3
1,2.0,a
2,3.0,
3,NaN,b
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are inserting in `Postgres`, for which both `nan` and `None` should be `NULL`, you can do this:

```
df.to_csv('file.csv', na_rep='NULL')
```